# Bundler::RubyVersionMisMatch when Rails controller invokes external script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

Ubuntu 20 > Apache 2.4 > Passenger 6 > ruby 2.7.4 > Rails 6.1 > `ruby script`

I'm invoking a ruby script via backticks from within a Rails controller (and collecting a return integer).

In production, somwhere in this chain, something is insisting on trying to run the ruby script with ruby 2.7.0 (the native system version) and complaining that it should be 2.7.4 (which it should).

The Rails app itself runs fine until I invoke a script.

When invoking the script, Passenger (I think?) is logging in the Apache error.log with

```
/home/rcm/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!':
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.4 (Bundler::RubyVersionMisMatch)
```

I have searched and tried numerous suggestions (most of which were already done).

- All scripts use: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
- $PATH includes `/home/rcm/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:...` and the usual suspects (I see that's rather explicit with /home/rcm/.rbenv instead of ~/.rbenv --- does it matter?)
- The apache .conf file has: `PassengerRuby /home/rcm/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/ruby`
- I have .ruby-version files at every layer I can think of specifying 2.7.4
- I have used rbenv to declare `global 2.7.4`.
- I have updated bundler.
- I have run bundle install.
- Restarted apache, rebooted the system, etc.

I can't figure out where in the chain anything could be trying to run the script with 2.7.0.

It all works fine in dev mode on macOS and Ubuntu, and even works fine running the project in e -production mode with the built in Puma on both macOS and Ubuntu. Only in the full Apache > Passenger production mode is there a problem. So, I'm thinking it has to be Passenger that's confused, but it's running the Rails app itself just fine -- which makes *me* confused.

The screwy part is, this was all working fine, and "all of a sudden" I'm getting this failure. (No idea which bit I twiddled.)

Would appreciate any ideas to give me something new to chase. Thanks.

Comment: When you check `PATH` are you doing so from the command line? That is not the same as the `PATH` of the running Rails application, check `ENV['PATH']` inside Rails.

Answer (score 0):

`ruby` is not necessarily the same as the ruby running Rails. It will run whatever the first one it finds in its [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Since this is running on a webserver, this will be different from the PATH of your own user.

Use [`bundle exec ruby`](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html) to run the Ruby associated with the application.

The best thing to do is to not run a script, instead incorporate the script code as a class in your Rails project. This is faster and easier to test.

Comment: Thx. ENV['PATH'] is `/home/rcm/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin:...` (expected). Bundler's docs suggest that subshells invoked with backticks automatically use the bundler environment. I can't seem to figure out the syntax to make anything with bundle exec work in the controller. The scripts don't need any of the Rails environment anyway. They're a collection of stand-alone CLI commands used by several separate apps which talk to hardware devices. (So they won't be converted to Rails classes.) I'll keep poking at it.

Comment: @GregWillits I wouldn't expect `/home/rcm/.rbenv/` to be in PATH in production. Its possible the production Rails process does not have permission to access that directory.

Comment: @GregWillits Check `Process::UID.eid` to see what user ID the process is running as.

Comment: @Shwern re: "I wouldn't expect /home/rcm/.rbenv/ to be in PATH in production" — Really? It's explicity identified in Passenger. Is that not relevant? The rails app and scripts are in various locations in /var/www/rcmMfgTools which rcm is the owner, and www-data is the group. All 755 for now. I agree permissions could be thing, that's where I started, but not seeing the error if there is one. From within the Rails controller calling the script, `Process::UID.eid` returns 1000 which is the uid of the rcm user. Thx for continued thoughts.

Comment: @GregWillits I assumed `/home/rcm` was a user directory. You [enabled the Apache module](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/bionic/)? What does `which ruby` say?

Comment: @Shwern From CLI, which ruby > `/home/rcm/.rbenv/shims/ruby`. From the Rails controller, which ruby > `/usr/bin/ruby` which makes sense because that's the problem -- trying to using the wrong ruby. Buy wwwhhhyyyyy <he groans with clenched fists>. Correct, Passenger module is installed, enabled, and generally serving the Rails app just fine. Passenger specifies 2.7.4, gemfile specifies 2.7.4, and .ruby-version all over the places specifies 2.7.4. BTW, this is happening on two instances of the same setup. So it's not an odd one off. Thanks again.

Comment: @GregWillits Sure sounds like a PATH or permissions problem. Try running `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @Shwern Agreed. Just now realized if I remove the ruby version from the Gemfile this removes the error (expected, since the discontinuity is where the "mismatch" error comes from). At this point running the scripts on 2.7.0 vs 2.7.4 is not likely a problem. The Rails app I suspect is still 2.7.4 because of Passenger. For now, I'm thinking of just running with this workaround, and put us both out of our misery. I may try the rbenv and passenger lists for insights. $PATH starts with `/home/rcm/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...`

Comment: @GregWillits If they're truly stand-alone scripts don't use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Hard code their `#!` and treat them as executables.

Comment: @Shwern Yeah, was thinking of that yesterday, but dev & production path would be different. Oh — symlinks! Didn't think of that until now.

Comment: @GregWillits In Perl the install script translates the `#!`. I don't know about Ruby. A symlink to the application Ruby makes sense.